# SQLite select query with WHERE clause in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying to get the value from sqlite database table, I wrote a `SELECT` query for retrieving the value from table. In that select query I have to check `CALLTYPE` field contains X or Y. In that `CALLTYPE` field contains the X or Y value I have to retrieve the `CALLTYPE` and  `ID` fields.

```
cursor=database.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{CALLTYPE,ID}, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: What do you want to know? What's inside the CALLTYPE Field?.

Comment: what problem you are facing

Comment: thanks for your replay, i got it.

Answer (score 3):

don't tested it, but something like that should work

```
Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{CALLTYPE,ID}, "CALLTYPE LIKE ? or CALLTYPE LIKE ?", new String[] { "%X%", "%Y%"}, null, null, null);
```

Comment: you got to it before me just make edit to the like clause as `like ?`